# Does JGit support Git Credentials?

Tags: git, credentials, jgit

Does JGit support Git Credentials as documented here: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials?

I haven't found yet anything to this topic.

Answer (score 6):

The counterpart to Git Credentials in JGit is the `CredentialsProvider` interface. All commands that establish connections to remote repositories can be configured with a `CredentialsProvider` instance. They inherit from `TransportCommand` which has a `setCredentialsProvider` method.

Comment: This would mean, that these part has still to be implemented because I haven't found yet any CredentialsProvider which would support to read out the credentials from these "Git credentials" stores?

Comment: Right, the Git credential cache/store is not implemented in JGit. But you should be able to implement a CredentialProvider yourself that reads from `.gitcredentials` if that is what you need. 

To let the JGit team know that you're interested in such a feature you may also want to file an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JGit) or post to the [developer mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/jgit-dev)

Comment: There's an [open bug on JGit for this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=441198) but it hasn't seen a lot of action.