# how to clone ssh remote repository using jgit and apache ant task?

Tags: git, ant, ssh, git-clone, jgit

I have a remote repository with address `ssh://user@host.com/git/repository/project.git`
and password

And i need to clone it using jgit with ant task. Unfortunately i can't clone it with standard jgit git-clone ant task because i get auth error even before being able to type in the password. I tried checking for the solution, but no luck yet. What should i do? should i customize that task somehow?

I have no problem cloning that project with command line git command `git clone ssh://user@host.com/git/repository/project.git` and stating password after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparently [JGit's clone task](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.ant/src/org/eclipse/jgit/ant/tasks/GitCloneTask.java) doesn't support password authentication. If you really want to authenticate with a password (the password would end up in the build.xml file) you'd have to write your own ant task or enhance the one that comes with JGit.

With `CloneCommand#setCredentialsProvider()` you can specify a [`CredentialsProvider`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173250/does-jgit-support-git-credentials/23184716#23184716) that can pass on the password from the Ant task to the command.